# why is Async not defined as it's own function in My project?

Tags: javascript, json, asynchronous, solidity

I am writing a smart contract and it involves making a swap/trade web app I have gone through it over and over to try to assume it was a flaw in my syntax possibly, this example and tutorial don't look like that, and also in my other contract, it is not showing as the correct family.  the best way I can describe it to you is "async" is purple in the examples along with "await" and '=' are also purple, it is appearing as the same color as "require" "let" and "const" in my project, I've spent forever and it all went well until I used chai to run the test, its saying reference error,  the same issue appears in my contract 2_deploy_contracts.js I just need someone to relief me please and tell me what I am doing incorrectly? here's the terminal where I run the truffle test The second is the snippet from Codepen.

`ReferenceError: EthSwap is not defined
at Object. (C:\Users\Noahm\eth_swap\test\EthSwap.test.js:3:1)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1108:14)
at loader (C:\Users\Noahm\eth_swap\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:144:5)
at Object.require.extensions. [as .js] (C:\Users\Noahm\eth_swap\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:154:7)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:988:32)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:828:14)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1012:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:93:18)
at C:\Users\Noahm\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js:390:36
at Array.forEach ()
at Mocha.loadFiles (C:\Users\Noahm\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js:387:14)
at Mocha.run (C:\Users\Noahm\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js:961:10)
at C:\Users\Noahm\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\core\lib\testing\Test.js:151:1
at new Promise ()
at Object.run (C:\Users\Noahm\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\core\lib\testing\Test.js:150:1)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at Object.run (C:\Users\Noahm\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\core\lib\commands\test\index.js:165:1)
at Command.run (C:\Users\Noahm\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\core\lib\command.js:140:1)
Truffle v5.3.4 (core: 5.3.4)
Node v16.0.0

```js
const Token = artifacts.require("Token");
const EthSwap = artifacts.require("EthSwap");

module.exports = async function(deployer) {
  // Deploy Token
  await deployer.deploy(Token);
  const token = await Token.deployed()

  // Deploy EthSwap
  await deployer.deploy(EthSwap);
  const ethSwap = await EthSwap.deployed()

  // transfer all tokens to EthSwap (1 million)
  await token.transfer(ethSwap.address, '1000000000000000000000000')
};
```

`